# Where in the Temple does the Shechina sit?

Tags: beis-hamikdash

1. The Temple is G-d's "דירה בתחתונים"
   (see תנחומא נשא טז: "**נתאוה הקב"ה להיות לו דירה בתחתונים**"
2. G-d sits on a chair ([כיסא כבוד](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%90_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93)) in Heaven
3. The Temple includes a Menorah, a table, a private chamber (K"K), but no chair(s).

Where is the Shechina supposed to sit in her "דירה בתחתונים"?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.99.1 https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.25.18

Comment: @Heshy Very interesting! But it bears no resemblance, the Aron doesn't have legs and the four animals? Also Aron resides in the private area, but the throne has to be seen to all, I think.

Answer (score 2):

A number of Rishonim believe that the Aron / Kaporet represent G-d's Throne.

[Ibn Ezra Shemot 25:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.25.22.1?lang=bi):

> על כן **הארון דמות כסא**.‏
>
> Thus **the Aron is the form of a throne**.

[Ramban Shemot 25:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Exodus.25.21?lang=bi):

> כי בעבור שיצוה בכרובים להיותם פורשי כנפים למעלה, ולא אמר למה יעשם כלל, ומה שישמשו במשכן, ולמה יהיו בענין הזה, לכך אמר עתה ונתת הכפרת עם כרוביו, שהכל דבר אחד על הארון מלמעלה, **כי אל הארון תתן את העדות אשר אתן אליך, כדי שיהיה לי כסא כבוד**, כי אני אועד לך שם ואשכין שכינתי עליהם, ודברתי אתך מעל הכפרת מבין שני הכרובים, בעבור שהוא על ארון העדות: והנה הוא כמרכבה אשר ראה יחזקאל שאמר היא החיה אשר ראיתי תחת אלהי ישראל בנהר כבר ואדע כי כרובים המה, ולכך נקרא יושב הכרובים.‏
>
> Since He had commanded that the Keruvim should have spread their wings upwards, but did not explain at all why they were to be made at all, and what purpose they would serve in the Mishkan, and why they should be like this. Therefore, He said now "Place the Kaporet, with its Keruvim, that it should be one with the Aron, above it. **For in to the Aron you should put the testimony which I have given you, so that it be my Throne of Glory**. For I will meet with you there and place my Shechinah above them, and I wil speak to you from between the two Keruvim, as they are above the Aron of testimony."
>
> Behold, this is like the Chariot which Yechezkel saw, when he said, "That was the Chayah which I saw beneath the G-d of Israel at the River Kevar, and I knew that they were Keruvim." That is why G-d is referred to as "the one who sits the Keruvim".

[Seforno Shemot 25:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Sforno_on_Exodus.25.23.1?lang=bi):

> אחר **מעשה הארון שהיה כדמות כסא לשכינה**, כאמרו ונועדתי לך שם. ציוה על שלחן ומנורה כמנהגם לפני השרים.‏
>
> After **the Aron which is like a throne for the Shechinah**, as it says, "And I will meet with you there," He commanded regarding the table and lamp, as is customary for the nobility to have.

---

I have also heard contemporary speakers link the Golden Mizbe'ach (on which the incense was burned and produced smoke) to G-d's Throne (see [here](https://www.zomet.org.il/?CategoryID=160&ArticleID=5629) for an example). This is based on [Yeshayahu 6](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.6?lang=bi) (I beheld my Lord **seated on a high and lofty throne**; and the skirts of His robe filled the Temple ... and the House kept **filling with smoke**).